# Why is the add to database function(ATDB) not working with php oop?

Tags: php, html, sql, oop, mysqli

This is where I keep all the class functions that I plan to execute throughout the program. Im fairly new to oop with php and I can't get this to work.

```
    <?php 

class DatabaseFunctions
{
public $link;
private $hostname = "localhost";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "root";
private $db = "data";

function __construct($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db)
{
    $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);

}

function ATDB($firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email)
{
    $sql= "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, telephone, email) VALUES
    ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$telephone', '$email')";

    mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);

}

function DFDB($firstname, $lastname)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE firstname='$firstname' AND WHERE lastname='$lastname";

    mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
}

function GetUsers()
{
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users");

    $results = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
}

function UTDB($firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email)
{
    $sql = ("UPDATE users 
    SET firstname = '$firstname',
    lastname = '$lastname',
    telephone = '$telephone',
    email = '$email'
    WHERE ID = '$id'
    ");

    mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
}

function SDB($search_text_1, $search_text_2)
{
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM 
    data
    WHERE
    lastname LIKE '$search_text_2' 
    OR 
    firstname LIKE '$search_text_1'");

    mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
}

}



?>
```

and on this form is where I try to execute the function ATDB function but it won't work.

```
    <html>
<head>
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Add to database</h1>

<form method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">

<p>Firstname
<input type="text" name="firstname" /> </p>

<p>Lastname
<input type="text" name="lastname" /> </p>

<p>Telephone
<input type="tel" name="telephone" size="10" /> </p>

<p>Email
<input type="text" name="email" /> </p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
</body>

</html>

<?php 
include("connect.php");
$db = new DatabaseFunctions;

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$db->ATDB('$firstname', '$lastname', '$telephone', '$email');

?>
```

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small rewrite to your class. Read it carefully and learn. Use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) a lot. Also read this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
class DatabaseFunctions
{
    public $link;
    private $hostname = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "root";
    private $db = "data";

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);
    }

    function ATDB($firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email)
    {
        $q = $this->link->prepare('INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, telephone, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');

        $q->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email);
        $q->execute();
    }

    function DFDB($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $q = $this->link->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE firstname=? AND lastname=?');

        $q->bind_param('ss', $firstname, $lastname);
        $q->execute();
    }

    function GetUsers()
    {
        $result = $this->link->query('SELECT * FROM users');

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            //some operations
            echo $row->firstname;
            echo $row->lastname;
        }
    }

    function UTDB($firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email, $id)
    {
        $q = $this->link->prepare('UPDATE users 
        SET firstname = ?,
        lastname = ?,
        telephone = ?,
        email = ?
        WHERE ID = ?
        ');

        $q->bind_param('ssssi', $firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email, $id);
        $q->execute();
    }

}
```

Construct object and calling function

```
$db = new DatabaseFunctions();

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$db->ATDB($firstname, $lastname, $telephone, $email);
```

Comment: Is this still using mysqli?

Comment: this still didn't work for me, I'm doing this on mamp if that makes a difference?

Comment: No difference at all. It's using object version of `mysqli`. Did you check everything very carefully?

Comment: Yes it works now minor code issue, but now the DFDB function isn't working

Comment: Mmmm I did copy/paste your code... There is `WHERE firstname=? AND WHERE lastname=?`. It have to be `WHERE firstname=? AND lastname=?`